# ReactJS - Render ReactDom on multiple dynamic ids

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6, orchardcms

**Hi All,**

I am using React.js for some UI components in Asp.net MVC CMS (Orchard) where I want to render a react component on a cshtml page multiple times (depends on user) with dynamic ids. E.g. I am generating a GUID on cshtml page and creating a **div** by appending GUID in div's id on this page. As this page/view will act like a partial view and can be added number of times from Admin panel to a single page by the Admin.

**index.cshtml:**

```
var id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().HtmlClassify();

<div class="container clearfix htmlcontent" id="modelCodeLookupContainer_@id">
```

**index.tsx:**

```
//and render it with something like below:
ReactDOM.render(
    <ModelCodeLookUpReact />,
    document.getElementById('modelCodeLookupContainer_' + id)
);
```

Please advise.

Comment: Tell me how are you passing the id (GUID) which is generated on the cshtml page to the ReactDOM.render() ? Instead of doing this make a AJAX call to the server which will do server side rendering of this new component and return the html, then you can use dangerouslySetInnerHTML={responseMarkup()} to show the new component.

Comment: Well, you can't. As there is no link between the 2, however, you could extend the class selector so that the panels where you wish to send the react panel to are as unique as possible and then use `document.querySelectorAll('.unique-class-name').forEach( panel => ReactDOM.render( <ModelCodeLookUpReact />, panel ) )` to render it to all matching panels

Comment: @AbhayShiro - I have created a hidden text field in cshtml file for guid `value like <input id="guid" type="text" value="@id" hidden />  ` and getting it in tsx file like this `ReactDOM.render(
    <ModelCodeLookUpReact />,
    document.getElementById('modelCodeLookupContainer_' + (document.getElementById('guid') as HTMLInputElement).value)
);`

Comment: If thats the case why not try this: ReactDOM.render(
    <ModelCodeLookUpReact />,
    document.getElementById('modelCodeLookupContainer_' + document.getElementById("guid"))
);

Comment: @AbhayShiro It renders the component only on the first div on cshtml file as it gets the first GUID everytime. I was trying to get GUID `document.getElementById('guid') as HTMLInputElement).value` in `componentDidMount()` method and store it in a global variable say "id" but `ReactDOM.render` is not accessing this global variable.

Comment: ReactDOM.render within a React component that doesn't get rendered. This is why i was asking you a different approach mentioned above

Comment: @Icepickle you suggestion worked for me in this case. thank you. but if I need to load dynamic and different data from server with axios call on a single react component. e.g. same component render in a cshtml partial view page should give result ABC but if Admin select another partial view of this component from CMS's admin panel with different data then it should give different result on this rendered component say XYZ. how can we achieve this?

Comment: Well how do you plan to differentiate between the 2? Where will your data come from?